# TypeError while trying to crop images on opencv

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror, contour, opencv3.0

I am trying to crop images from the video but it's not showing the result. I know that TypeError is happening because there is no content in crop crop_img but since I am a beginner in opencv so I don't know the solution of it. Below code I copied from project which uses opencv with raspberry pi & webcam to follow the line. Now I am trying to test in on my windows 10 so maybe some interfacing issues are possible.

code:-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
video_capture.set(3, 160)
video_capture.set(4, 120)

while(True):
    # Capture the frames

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    #print("image recieved");
    #cv2.imshow('frame',ret)

    # Crop the image

    crop_img = frame[60:120, 0:160]


    cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)



    # Convert to grayscale

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Gaussian blur

    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)

    cv2.imshow('show', blur)

    # Color thresholding

    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,60,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # Find the contours of the frame

    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), 1, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)



    # Find the biggest contour (if detected)

    if len(contours) > 0:

        c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        cv2.line(crop_img,(cx,0),(cx,720),(255,0,0),1)
        cv2.line(crop_img,(0,cy),(1280,cy),(255,0,0),1)
        cv2.drawContours(crop_img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)

        if cx >= 120:
            print ("Turn Left!")

        if cx < 120 and cx > 50:
            print ("On Track!")

        if cx <= 50:
            print ("Turn Right")
        else:
            print ("I don't see the line")
    #Display the resulting frame

    cv2.imshow('frame',crop_img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break\
```

Error:-

```
runfile('C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Desktop/Sultan/Veggitech/Transport robot with Voice Control/Code/Test Code/line_follower_opencv.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Desktop/Sultan/Veggitech/Transport robot with Voice Control/Code/Test Code')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-583afe4334df>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Desktop/Sultan/Veggitech/Transport robot with Voice Control/Code/Test Code/line_follower_opencv.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Desktop/Sultan/Veggitech/Transport robot with Voice Control/Code/Test Code')

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Desktop/Sultan/Veggitech/Transport robot with Voice Control/Code/Test Code/line_follower_opencv.py", line 25, in <module>
    crop_img = frame[60:120, 0:160]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I don't know anything about cv2 but your video_capture seems empty. Can you please run this: `video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` and then: `if video_capture: print('Yes')`. Does this print Yes?

Comment: actually I just now tried cv2.video_capture(0) and that worked. Altho there are other errors now. cv2.video_capture(-1) gives same error

Comment: video_capture(0) reads from the default device camera. what are the other errors you are facing ?

Comment: Just FYI, please keep one post to one specific question, and post new questions separately.

Comment: alright @FatihAkici, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some [issue](https://answers.opencv.org/question/208834/cv2videocapture0read-return-always-none-value/) with the specifying `-1` as your camera in the line

`video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)`

because of which your code is not able to locate the camera and so it is returning `None`. So try explicitly giving the camera id like this:

`video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

assuming that you are working with only one camera.